# Matrix Calculator Without NumPy - Passing Parameters to other functions

Tags: python, function, matrix, parameters, calculator

So I'm building a matrix calculator without NumPy and I have a limited but working model. However that model is very rough and I would like to improve upon it as well as expand its functionality to be able to compute multiple matrices and interact with each other (multiplication for example).

A problem I have quickly run into with my very limited experience with Python is the passing of variables between multiple functions (parameters I believe they're called). Here is what I have:

```
def matrixGenerator1():
    rows = int(input("\nHow many rows are in the matrix?\n\n:"))
    columns = int(input("\nHow many columns are in the matrix?\n\n:"))
    matrix1 = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)]
    for y in range(rows):
        for x in range(columns):
            matrix1[y][x] = int(input("\nWhat is the entry?\n\n:"))
    print("\nThe original matrix is...")
    for y in range(rows):
        print("\n")
        for x in range(columns):
            print(format(matrix1[y][x], "5d"), end="")
    return rows, columns, matrix1


def matrixTranspose(rows, columns, matrix1):
    print("\nThe transpose of this matrix is...")
    for y in range(rows):
        print("\n")
        for x in range(columns):
            print(format(matrix1[y][x], "5d"), end="")

matrixGenerator1()
matrixTranspose(rows, columns, matrix1)
```

Running this results in an error message saying that `rows`,`columns`, and `matrix1` are not defined. I realize that these variables are local to the `matrixGenerator` function and forcing them to be global is not an option I want to embrace.

Is there anyway that someone could provide me a general explanation as to what I'm doing wrong so I can prevent this error in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the output of your first function in your main routine. (Notice you are already returning it so you are almost done):

```
rows, columns, matrix1 = matrixGenerator1()
matrixTranspose(rows, columns, matrix1)
```

Comment: Implementing that assignment statement above the call to 'matrixTranspose' unintentionally prompts me for input again. The program should just carry the input from the 'matrixGenerator' function through the remainder of the program. Is there another way to use parameters but avoid the prompt for extraneous input? I should note that my previous iteration of this program didn't have a function to generate the matrix and was instead all in the main routine. I'd like to achieve something similar.

Comment: You replaced your original call to matrixGenerator1(), right? I ran it and it did not prompt me twice.

Comment: That makes sense, I misunderstood. That solved the problem, thank you.